# How to add a separate folder for the mail coming from a specific person's mail ID in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I received lot of important mail from many people. It's very clumsy to look at them all in my Inbox. I want to have a separate folder for each individual person. Is it possible to implement this with Thunderbird? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the inbox you want to add a folder to, then select `New Folder` and name it whatever you want, then to filter message into it, go to `Tools->Message filters` and add a `New` filter; call it whatever you want, choose how you want it run, then select `Match all of the following` and choose `From` in the first box and `is` in the second box and put the email of the person you want to filter and click the `+`. In the `Preform these actions` panel, choose `Move Message to` in the first drop down and select the folder in the second drop down that you want to move the message to.

[here's a link](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=143142) explaining more as well and [here's the Thunderbird](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters?s=message+filter&as=s) link on filters.

Comment: Glad I could help :)